# $unset an attribute of an array element in all arrays and documents under certain conditions

Tags: mongodb

I hope the title of this post is a good summary of my problem

I have some documents in my collection which look like this:

```
    {
      "positionGroups": [
        { "positions":
          [
            {
              "catalogIds": [ "ynd7476ghfnjfu84", "nhczf74ufju48" ],
              "catalog_ids": [ 5, 6 ]
            },
            {
              "catalogIds": [ "nhczf74ufju48", "bfur74zf48urj48" ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { "positions":
          [
            {
              "catalogIds": [ "ynd7476ghfnjfu84", "hg757ghz5775uf8d9je9" ],
              "catalog_ids": [ 5, 8 ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to remove the `catalogIds` arrays from all positions, which contain a `catalog_ids` array.

I tried this, using the [filtered positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").update(
  {},
  { $unset: { 'positionGroups.$[].positions.$[elem].catalogIds': 1 } },
  { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.catalog_ids': { $exists: 1 } }], multi: true });
```

But got this in Studio 3T Intellishell:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1231, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

Nothing was upserted or modified.

I tried it even without the arrayFilters using updateMany:

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").updateMany(
  {},
  { $unset: { 'positionGroups.$[].positions.$[].catalogIds': 1 } }
);
```

getting this:

```
{ 
    "acknowledged" : true, 
    "matchedCount" : 1231.0, 
    "modifiedCount" : 0.0
}
```

Again nothing modified.

Comment: Try below query
  db.getCollection("collectionName").update(
  {},
  { $unset: { 'positionGroups.$[].positions.$[].catalogIds': 1 } },
  { multi: true }
 )

Comment: What MongoDB version do you have? I'm working on 4.0.10 and your first query works... I just inserted the given document, ran it, and I do get the `catalogIds` unset when a `catalog_ids` is present... Result: `{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e7afa2f8c863075684dfb"),
 "positionGroups" : [
  {
   "positions" : [
    {
     "catalog_ids" : [
      5,
      6
     ]
    },
    {
     "catalogIds" : [
      "nhczf74ufju48",
      "bfur74zf48urj48"
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "positions" : [
    {
     "catalog_ids" : [
      5,
      8
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: @Ptijohn gave the right hint. I'm working with MongoDB 3.2. All positional operator and filtered positional operator are available from v3.6.

Is their a solution for my problem without positional operators?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no solution for that with the positional operators.. Especially considering the fact that you have two arrays within the other. With only one you could have hoped using the `$` operator. But not here. Should I post an answer suggesting an upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments above, the `arrayFilter` is only available starting version 3.6 of MongoDB.

Your first solution works as intended on a more recent MongoDB:

```
> db.test_array.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e79b42f8c863075684df8"),
    "positionGroups" : [
        {
            "positions" : [
                {
                    "catalogIds" : [
                        "ynd7476ghfnjfu84",
                        "nhczf74ufju48"
                    ],
                    "catalog_ids" : [
                        5,
                        6
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "catalogIds" : [
                        "nhczf74ufju48",
                        "bfur74zf48urj48"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "positions" : [
                {
                    "catalogIds" : [
                        "ynd7476ghfnjfu84",
                        "hg757ghz5775uf8d9je9"
                    ],
                    "catalog_ids" : [
                        5,
                        8
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
> db.test_array.updateMany({},{ $unset: { 'positionGroups.$[].positions.$[elem].catalogIds': 1 } }, { arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.catalog_ids': { $exists: 1 } }]})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.test_array.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e79b42f8c863075684df8"),
    "positionGroups" : [
        {
            "positions" : [
                {
                    "catalog_ids" : [
                        5,
                        6
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "catalogIds" : [
                        "nhczf74ufju48",
                        "bfur74zf48urj48"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "positions" : [
                {
                    "catalog_ids" : [
                        5,
                        8
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately there's no solution for your case before MongoDB 3.6, except fetching all the documents, modifying them in a program, and then updating them.

Side note: I would advise you to always use `updateOne` and `updateMany` instead of `update` with the `multi` option. It's far more error prone, and with `updateOne/Many` you know exactly what you are doing.